# My simple react.js app is a blank page on my phone (but works on my desktop and tablet). Why?

Tags: reactjs

I am toying with react.js. I created a [simple-minded app](http://lleague.sgkruk.webfactional.com/lleague.html)
It works on my desktop and on my android tablet, but I get a blank page, nothing else, on my phone, whether in the Android browser or in Firefox.

And yes, I did add the required

```
React.initializeTouchEvents(true);
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: These answers look helpful for a blank screen in React: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56054235/how-to-fix-the-white-screen-after-build-with-create-react-app

Answer (score 1):

The `<script>` tag that includes your JS, main.js, is inside `document.body` but is also rendering your React component to `document.body` and overwriting itself. Try rendering to the container you provided and see if that fixes it:

**Current:**

```
React.renderComponent(RotationContainer( {data:DATA} ), document.body);
```

**Change to render to `#content`:**

```
React.renderComponent(
  RotationContainer( {data:DATA} ),
  document.querySelector("#content")
);
```