# How to fix the white screen after build with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, build, react-router, create-react-app, react-router-v4

I  used `react-router-dom` and I build my react-app. When I deploy it on the server, I get a blank page and the console is empty.

My App.js is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Agenda from './components/Agenda/Agenda';
import Planning from './components/Planning/Planning';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter  basename="/">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/"  component={Agenda} />
            <Route path="/planning" component={Planning} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My index.js is :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
        <App/>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

My index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon"  href="favicon.ico">
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet"> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css"/>
     <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
     <link rel="data" href="data.json">
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my package.json, I have :

```
"homepage": "."
```

And when I change my `homepage` to `https://dev.test.com/React`and 
 when I run it, I get a blank page, such as the address, which I deployed is : `https://dev.test.com/React/` It is not public. When I run `serve-s build`, I get a blank screen on the console, I get:

[image]

My index.html on production is :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
        <link rel="data" href="data.json">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="/React/static/css/2.2aa93811.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/React/static/css/main.ca6e1d23.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script>!function(f){function e(e){for(var r,t,n=e[0],o=e[1],u=e[2],l=0,a=[];l<n.length;l++)t=n[l],c[t]&&a.push(c[t][0]),c[t]=0;for(r in o)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,r)&&(f[r]=o[r]);for(s&&s(e);a.length;)a.shift()();return p.push.apply(p,u||[]),i()}function i(){for(var e,r=0;r<p.length;r++){for(var t=p[r],n=!0,o=1;o<t.length;o++){var u=t[o];0!==c[u]&&(n=!1)}n&&(p.splice(r--,1),e=l(l.s=t[0]))}return e}var t={},c={1:0},p=[];function l(e){if(t[e])return t[e].exports;var r=t[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return f[e].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,l),r.l=!0,r.exports}l.m=f,l.c=t,l.d=function(e,r,t){l.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},l.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},l.t=function(r,e){if(1&e&&(r=l(r)),8&e)return r;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof r&&r&&r.__esModule)return r;var t=Object.create(null);if(l.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:r}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof r)for(var n in r)l.d(t,n,function(e){return r[e]}.bind(null,n));return t},l.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return l.d(r,"a",r),r},l.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},l.p="/ReactCalendar/";var r=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],n=r.push.bind(r);r.push=e,r=r.slice();for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)e(r[o]);var s=n;i()}([])</script>
        <script src="/React/static/js/2.4a7f0704.chunk.js"></script>
        <script src="/React/static/js/main.f9268394.chunk.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Is `/React` a directory on your server? Also can you provide the compiled `index.html` from your production build?

Comment: @Rallen yes `/React` is a directory on my server, can you chek my post please ? I add the compiled `index.html` on production. When I run it on my server, the console is empty.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try changing `basename="/"` on your `BrowserRouter` to `basename="/React"`. `react-router` needs this if used in a sub-directory.

From the [`react-router` docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string):

> **basename**: The base URL for all locations. If your app is served from a sub-directory on your server, you'll want to set this to the sub-directory. A properly formatted basename should have a leading slash, but no trailing slash.

Also change `homepage` in `package.json` to the url of your production target. `homepage="."` means it will work on every domain where it is located in the server root (and is also the default behaviour).

From the [React docs regarding deployment](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment):

> By default, Create React App produces a build assuming your app is hosted at the server root.
>   To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json, for example:
>
> ```
> "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath",
> ```
>
> This will let Create React App correctly infer the root path to use in the generated HTML file.

Comment: The homepage will be  `"homepage":"."` or `"homepage":"https://dev.test.com/React"` ?

Comment: Hi! Can you please share which homepage you ended using? I've been trying so many variations. Does need to be `http` or `https`? What should go where `relativepath` is?

Comment: I had to use my domain's exact BASE URL instead of '.' in "homepage" because it was not showing images. Besides that this method worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same problem and solved it!

If anyone has still this issue, follow the following steps.

1 - You need to update your browser. Refer to this, https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/#configuring-supported-browsers

2- You need to add `"react-router-dom":` dependency to your package.json file using `npm i react-router-dom`

3- Add `"homepage": ".",` to your package.json file

Hope this helps.

Comment: Only Add "homepage": ".", to your package.json file

Comment: I've done this and still no luck

Answer (score 6):

I also had this problem, blank white screen, no errors. None of these answers solved my problem. 
 I'm gonna leave the solution to my problem here, so that someone else like me wont spent 2 hours on a small mistake.

Just make sure you upload all files in `/build` folder to the server.

Comment: I did the same! my issue still persists. I just uploaded all my files from the build folder to s3. When I load my S3, it is showing blank screen and no errors.

Answer (score 6):

What's worked for me is adding `basename="/index.html"` to the BrowserRouter :

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/index.html">
   ...
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: It's a real disaster how many different answers there are. And all of them seem to have helped somebody. This one helped me!
I am running Nginx on Linux.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same "white screen" issue, I solved with just adding:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/">
```

`basename="/"` in the index.js file.

that worked for me, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding an additional answer, as I know there are many causes for this. I was experiencing a white page following build, and saw a 404 in browser console for web chunks. I'd set 'homepage' in package.json, and was perplexed.

### Server side caching

However, I noticed in the 404 message, the chunk being referenced *had a different hash than the one in my build folder*; these "old" chunks were trying to be fetched, and not the new ones from the latest build with different hashes in the filename.

e.g, the 404 error in my browser console was pointing to a chunk with a hash something like:

```
main.f1d2d060.chunk.css // from an old build
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

Where as in `/build` folder, the chunk was actually:

```
main.adg25e108.chunk.css // from latest build
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

Thus I realized some file must be cached trying to retrieve the old thing rather than the new. Turned out I'd had **server-side caching** enabled, and the old web chunks were trying to be retrieved by a cached version of `asset-manifest.json`... :sigh: ...I was able to flush the cache for my web host (SiteGround).

Flushing cache will vary depending upon your host: https://www.siteground.com/kb/clear-site-cache/

Something to consider if you've tried everything else -- double and triple check the hash string in the 404 in your console matches that in your /build folder, else you might be in the same situation with an old asset-manifest.json trying to retrieve the wrong stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I just add `basename='/index.html'` on my index.html, see code below for more :

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage/LoginPage';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard/Dashboard';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router basename='/index.html'>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hope it would help.

Answer (score 3):

Rearranging like this worked for me, remove exact? from root path

```
<Router>
  <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Router>
```

Comment: I used hompage="." in my package.json but '/about' not going to the relative path

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. I was trying to open the application after build with double-clicking the index.html and didn't work either, I got the blank page  but if the built files are run in a server environment works.  https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers work for me. So I tried to run it in a different port and it works.

```
serve -s build -l 4000
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to a page whose route you've renamed.

I had a white screen that showed no errors, because I was using `history.push` to send the user to a page that we had renamed.

The page no longer existed, so it displayed a blank white screen.

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue with react-router-dom v6, What has worked for me is replacing `<BrowserRouter>` with `<HashRouter>` and adding `"homepage": "."` in package.json

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/index"
import SignInPage from "./pages/signin";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
     <Home />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/signin' component={SignInPage}/>
      </Routes>
   </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have tried all of the above and none has worked. I am doing a code along where Switch was used in the BrowserRouter but the docs say to use Routes in place of Switch.
In the second code, I put  component back in and the site came back but it still will not route, not sure why.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/index";
import SignInPage from "./pages/signin";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/signin' component={SignInPage}/>
      </Routes>
   </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: OK, the components should be {<Home/>} and {<SignInPage/>} this fixed it and I removed the lone <Home/>, Router now works!

Answer (score 0):

If getting blank page without any console errors then issue is in configuration of Router.

Normally happens when u are moving the build file to a particular location in server.

Basename must match where u are running the file in the address bar.

If url of address bar reads: http://localhost:3333/build/index.html
then basename will be /build/index.html

otherwise if u are running on http://localhost:3333/index.html then basename will be /index.html etc. its the path after first slash.

If its just '/' then make it same on basename

...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem while running my code (before deployment) and after pulling my hair out decided to boot up another project and tried running it, and it did the same thing... white page and shows its loading. Figured it must be an issue with IISExpress, so I restarted my computer and the problem went away immediately.