# Getting blank screen after hosting my react project to the server

Tags: reactjs

I have hosted my react project to the server, but after deployment it shows blank screen and on console there is no error shown, but in my localhost it is running fine,
This is my index.html file in public folder,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta  charset="utf-8"/>
  
  <title>React Form Builder </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    body {
      font-size: 14px;
      background: #fafafa;
      font-weight: 300;
      color: #404d5b;
       width: 98%; 
        /* height: 100; */
      margin:  20px;
   
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    .modal { background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);}
    .modal-content { padding: 30px; max-height: 800px; width: 600px ; margin-right:400px ; overflow-y: auto }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var FORM_ACTION = "/testing";
    var FORM_METHOD = "POST";
  </script>
  <div id="demo-bar"></div>
  <div id="form-builder"></div>
  <div id="show-form"></div>
  <script type="text/babel" src="/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My config file is

```
 var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.jsx',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./dist'),
    filename: 'app.js',
    library: 'ReactFormBuilder',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    publicPath: "/"
  },

  externals: {
    //don't bundle the 'react' npm package with our bundle.js
    //but get it from a global 'React' variable
    'react': {
      'commonjs': 'react',
      'commonjs2': 'react',
      'amd': 'react',
      'root': 'React'
    },
    'react-dom': {
      'commonjs': 'react-dom',
      'commonjs2': 'react-dom',
      'amd': 'react-dom',
      'root': 'ReactDOM'
    },
    // 'react-datepicker': 'react-datepicker',
    // 'classnames': 'classnames',
    // 'jquery': 'jquery',
    'bootstrap': 'bootstrap'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['./mjs', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.css', '.json'],
    alias: {
      "jquery": path.join(__dirname, "./jquery-stub.js")
    }
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.js|.jsx?$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'babel-loader' }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader', options: {
              sassOptions: {
                includePaths: ['./node_modules'],
              },
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  }
};
```

I have tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/56055153/14849817 but it doesn't help!

Comment: Where is it hosted? AWS / Netlify / Apache Server or anything else?

Comment: It is hosted in Apache server

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;

Can you try this in `.htaccess` file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

I reckon, this is an issue with your hosting on Apache server and not React.

> Step 1 : Create your app

```
$ npm install -g create-react-app 
$ create-react-app my-app
```

> Step 2 : Build it for production

```
$ cd my-app
$ npm run build
```

> Step 3 : deploy
> copy and paste everything in build folder to your server
> edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
...
AllowOverride All
...
</Directory>
```

create a “.htaccess” file in html directory and add this snippet :

````
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]```

or edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

<Directory "/var/www/html">
 #
 # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
 # or any combination of:
 #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
 #
 # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
 # doesn't give it to you.
 #
 # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
 # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
 # for more information.
 #
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

 #
 # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
 # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
 #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
 #
 AllowOverride All

 Options -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]

 #
 # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
 #
 Require all granted
</Directory>
````